# Android - Voice Recognizer Voice Intent Error Handling (C#)

Tags: c#, android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, recognizer-intent

```
public class createRecognizerIntent
{
    var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);

    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt,
    Application.Context.GetString(Resource.String.ApplicationName));
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, "de");
    voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
    StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);}
```

I have this code to create a recognizer intent. Now I want to restart the intent (the "createRecognizerIntent" Method) when an error appears. How can I realize this?

Comment: Please include the error (and stacktrace) if possible in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To restart intent, you have to create your own recognizer, this is my code on xamarin :

```
public class CustomRecognizer : Java.Lang.Object, IRecognitionListener, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{
private SpeechRecognizer _speech;
private Intent _speechIntent;


public string Words;


public CustomRecognizer(Context _context)
{
    this._context = _context;
    Words = "";
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech, RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000); 
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
}

void startover()
{
    _speech.Destroy();
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
StartListening();
}
public void StartListening()
{
    _speech.StartListening(_speechIntent);
}

public void StopListening()
{
    _speech.StopListening();
}

public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
{
}

public void OnEndOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
{
    Words = error.ToString();
    startover();
}

public void OnEvent(int eventType, Bundle @params)
{
}

public void OnPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
{
}

public void OnReadyForSpeech(Bundle @params)
{
}

public void OnResults(Bundle results)
{

    var matches = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
    if (matches == null)
        Words = "Null";
    else
        if (matches.Count != 0)
        Words = matches[0];
    else
        Words = "";

    //do anything you want for the result
    }
    startover();
}

public void OnRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
{

}

public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status)
{
    if (status == OperationResult.Error)
        txtspeech.SetLanguage(Java.Util.Locale.Default);
}}
```

you can just call **startover()** when something goes error (**OnError()**).